# Python, C: redirected stdout fires [Errno 9]

Tags: python, c, windows, stdout

I try to log all the output of a program written in Python and C. However, printing from Python causes `IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`

Please, does anyone know what the problem is and how to fix it?

PS: It's on Windows XP, Python 2.6 and MinGW GCC

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "Python.h"

int main()
{
    int fds[2];
    _pipe(fds, 1024, O_BINARY);
    _dup2(fds[1], 1);
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

/*  alternative version: */
//  HANDLE hReadPipe, hWritePipe; 
//  int fd;
//  DWORD nr;
//  CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, NULL, 0);
//  fd = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)hWritePipe, _O_BINARY);
//  _dup2(fd, 1);
//  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    write(1, "write\n", 6);
    printf("printf\n");
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("print 'print'"); // this breaks
    Py_Finalize();

    char buffer[1024];
    fprintf(stderr, "buffer size: %d\n", read(fds[0], buffer, 1024)); // should always be more than 0

/*  alternative version: */
//  CloseHandle(hWritePipe);
//  char buffer[1024];
//  ReadFile(hReadPipe, buffer, 1024, &nr, NULL);
//  fprintf(stderr, "buffer size: %d\n", nr); // should always be more than 0
}
```

Comment: Did you build Python yourself or are you trying to use prebuilt binaries?

Comment: prebuild ones, from python.org

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be to do with different C runtimes. I know you can't pass file descriptors between different C runtimes - Python is built with MSVC (you will need to check which version) - so you could try to make MinGW build against the same C runtime - I think there is options to do this in MinGW like -lmsvcrt80 (or whichever is the appropriate versions) but for licensing reasons they can't distribute the libraries so you will have to find them on your system. Sorry I don't have any more details on that for now, but hopefully its a start for some googling.

A simpler way would be to just do it all in Python... just make a class which exposes a `write` and perhaps `flush` method and assign it to sys.stdout. Eg for a file you can just pass an open file object - it's probably straightfoward to do a similar thing for your pipe. Then just import it and sys and set sys.stdout in a PyRun_SimpleString.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I'm sorry, I'm not sure I quite follow the thing with different runtimes... I tried:

gcc -o std.exe std.c -Ic:/dev/include/python2.6 -l python26 -l msvcr90

but then it crashes with "The application failed to initialize properly (0x80000003)."

Also, I don't have MSVC - could this be it? That I need msvcrt.lib from VC2008 (IIRC this was used for Python 2.6)? In MinGW I have several libmsvc*.a...

Comment: It's more involved than that to link against it with mingw but I'm afraid I don't have more details. It might be easiest to use the same microsoft compiler as Python used (I think visual studio 2008).

Comment: Or build Python yourself with MinGW - but no idea how easy that would be either.

Comment: Only thing I can find is ths: http://www.mail-archive.com/mingw-w64-public@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00285.html

Comment: I think I read somewhere (Python bug tracker) that building Python with MinGW is fairly difficult.  
Thanks for the links, though! I read them and I believe I have to read them once more, and once more, ...

Comment: Visual Studio 2008 Express edition is free - I think it would be much easier. Easier still would be just doing the stdout redirection in Python as I mentioned so you wouldn't have to pass a file handle from c to python - but I don't know if you need C and Python stdout going to the same place.

Comment: PyRun_SimpleString('import sys;f = open('out.log','w');sys.stdout,sys.stderr= f,f')

Comment: I would like to collect all the output to a memory buffer, instead of a file, so I can process it later. I hoped I wont need to install VS2008 just for this but yes, this is an option too. But now that I look at your code, it might be possible to pass a file object to Python, redirect stdio as you wrote and when PyRun_SimpleString() finishes, read that file. Of cource, the best thing would be if Python worked with MinGW so I'll try in that direction a bit more. Thanks a lot for the help!